# What is the difference between MKCoordinateSpan and CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

I was going through the sample example of `MapKit` and `CoreLocation` framework. I found these two structs (`MKCoordinateSpan` and `CLLocationCoordinate2D`) which are similar in declaration. How  are these different in functionality, can someone please site an example (using both) to clear their meanings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`MKCoordinateSpan` defines a *span*, i.e. a delta, in the latitude and longitude directions to show on a map. Along with a point you can then define a region to display on a map.

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` defines a single point in the latitude and longitude coordinate system.

For example:

```
|<---- deltaLat  ---->|
|---------------------|---
|                     | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|          +          |deltaLon
|      (lat,lon)      | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|                     | |
|---------------------|---
```

Here you can imagine a centre point `(lat,lon)` about which you have a `deltaLat` and a `deltaLon`.

So `(lat,lon)` would be a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and `deltaLat, deltaLon` would form a `MKCoordinateSpan`.

You're right that both structures are defined in the same way, but this is quite common where the two different structures have different semantics and therefore are defined separately like you've found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and one more thing i get to know here, thought i should share with you. Span is the zoom level here as per apple documentation. Lesser will be the delta higher will be the zoom level. This delta value is in float. Why does they took it in CLLocationDegrees?

Comment: Because it's a *delta*. i.e. it's defining the region like I've shown in the crude diagram. It's not defining a zoom level directly, it's defining exactly a region.

Answer (score 6):

`MKCoordinateSpan` is interpreted as *delta values*, whereas `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is interpreted as a *point*.

For example, let's say you want to define a circular region, you would define a center point, and the radius around it.

In `MapKit`, you define a *rectangular region* by `MKCoordinateRegion`. The center point is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (`latitude` and `longitude` - both typedef of `double`) and a vertical and horizontal delta by `MKCoordinateSpan` (`latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` - both typedef of `double`)

Comment: Thanks buddy..understood completely..:)